# При архивации маленькие файлы увеличиваются в размере

Tags: .net, архивация, gzip

Реализовываю многопоточный архиватор файл на .Net с помощью GzipStream (.Net 3.5.). Есть проблема со сжатием маленьких и плохо поддающихся сжатию файлов - после архивации увеличиваются в размерах. Так файл весом в 3 кб после архивации весит 124 кб. При переходе на Net 4.5.2. файл после архивации весит 23 кб(Подозреваю из-за того, что GzipStream в этой версии пользуется улучшенными алгоритмами для сжатия).
Проблема видимо связана с тем, что при сжатии в файл пишутся метаданные, которые весят больше, чем содержимое файла. 2 вопроса: действительно ли проблема в метаданных, или есть что-то еще не учтенное; можно ли как-то обойти возникшую проблему, чтобы небольшие файлы не разрастались до таких размеров?

Comment: Посмотрите тут очень похожий вопрос - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34894231/smaller-file-compressed-by-gzip-is-larger-than-the-big-one Проблема не совсем в метаданных, скорее в алгоритме сжатия.

Comment: Покажите ваш код с использованием GzipStream

Comment: https://github.com/R0manych/Archiever/blob/master/ArchieverApp/GZip/Compressor.cs

Comment: Попробуйте использовать [LZMA2](https://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) формат. У него лучше обстоят дела с плохо сжимаемыми файлами и файлами малого размера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> GZIP обеспечивает сжатие без потерь, иными словами, исходные данные
>   можно полностью восстановить при распаковке. Он основан на алгоритме
>   DEFLATE, который использует комбинацию алгоритма LZ77 и алгоритма
>   Хаффмана.
>   [источник](https://habr.com/post/221849/)
>
> Сжатие выполняется даже в том случае, если сжатый файл превышает
>   исходный по размеру. Самый неблагоприятный результат – увеличение на
>   несколько байтов, используемых для заголовка файла gzip, плюс на 5
>   байтов на каждый блок из 32 КБ либо, для крупных файлов, увеличение на
>   0,015%. При сжатии и распаковке утилита gzip сохраняет данные о режиме
>   и принадлежности, а также временные метки файлов.
>   [источник](http://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/manual/html_node/Overview.html)

LZ77 заменяет все вхождения ранее встречавшихся строк на "направления". Направления - это кортеж (длина, растояние). Растояние - как далеко назад на входе была строка и длина - склолько байт было сопоставлено. Минимальная длина 3, максимальная 258. Самая далекая дистанция - 32КБ. Вторым этапом все эти кортежи сжимаются алгоритмом Хаффмана

Т.е. если у вас размер файла в 3Кб то в зависимости от его структуры результат сжатия очень сложно предсказать, и то что добавит gzip к файлу, чтобы выполнить сжатие, вполне вероятно будет больше размера самого файла.

Обойти это используя gzip наверное никак невозможно это его особенность, может только объединив все мелкие файлы в один большой чтобы улучшить сжатие (tar).